# Reproducible Dynamic Causal Modeling/ model based effective connectivity analysis for fMRI

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, fmri, reproducible-research, spm

I am doing a Masters degree in Cognitive Neuroscience and was thinking on doing my master thesis on effective connectivity in Theory of Mind. I like the model-based approach of Dynamic Causal Modeling (DCM). I have been thinking about how to that analysis in a reproducible manner. I have been reading a lot recently about reproducible fMRI analysis methods, like using Nipype in a Docker container.

However, I am unsure about how I would be able to achieve the same kind of reproducibility when using SPM, in comparison to using Nipype and Docker, where I can document every step of the analysis in a Jupyter Notebook. Nipype only seems to have interfaces for preprocessing and first level analysis in SPM12, but not for any of the DCM functionality.

I also found a [Github repository](https://github.com/JohnGriffiths/mne-dcm) where someone tried to port DCM to MNE-python, but the last commit was two years ago, so I don't think anything will come after that.

Does any of you have an idea how to address this? Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add some reference on DCM, perhaps a link to fundamental software too...